# Send a complete object from JSP to action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

If suppose, I have a `List` of type `Schedule` on my JSP page. I iterate through it and wants to send a particular object of the list to the action class. Is this possible to do that using Struts 2? What I have explored is that I can send the value of the identifier variable of the object to the action class and then fetch the row corresponding to it there.

```jsp
<s:form action="FlightAction">
<s:iterator value="schedulelist" var="flight">
    <s:if test="#flight.sid==10">
        <s:hidden name="object" value="#flight"/>
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
        <s:submit value="Send"/>
</s:form>
```

Now what I want is when value of SID is 10, then the whole Schedule object is sent to the action class. `schedulelist` refers to a list that contains object of type Schedule. SID is the identifier variable of the Schedule POJO. Is sending a complete object in this way possible in Struts 2?

Comment: The only things HTTP/browsers send to the server are strings, period. You must send enough information to allow recreation of the object, or keep it in session in the first place. Keeping an arbitrary number of arbitrarily large objects in session has its own disadvantages.

Comment: @Dave So what u actually mean is that i should send the value of an identifier variable of the object to the action and fetch the record against that identifier in my action class?

Answer (score 0):

put the "Schedule" object you want to send to action class in request scope, and then you can access it in action class.

```
<s:set name="scheduleObj" value="%{scheduleList.get(2)}" scope="request" />
```

The above example puts 3'rd object into scheduleObj request variable.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. This puts an object into the request scope for the *current* request. If you hit an action after the JSP is rendered you've made a *new* request, and the object will *not* be available in the action.

Comment: huh? Its been long since I wrote JSP/struts code, but I think this will do. Else, try scope="session". What do you think.?

Comment: I think once you hit the JSP, calling action code requires a new request. Putting stuff into the request scope in the view layer almost never makes sense unless you're specifically doing something like using an `<s:action>` tag.

Comment: @Dave u r correct. I tried doing it, and it happened just as u mentioned above. I couldn't understand the reason. Your comment really helped me understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```jsp
<s:hidden name="object.sid" value="%{#flight.sid}"/>
```

Then you be able to send the value to the action to the `object` of type `Schedule` which you have to create and provide `getObject(), setSid()` methods.

If you want to populate a collection of objects of type `Schedule`, then you need to use indexing.

```jsp
<s:hidden name="object[%{#status.index}].sid" value="%{#flight.sid}"/>
```

Read the [Struts Type Conversion: Collections and Map support](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-CollectionandMapSupport).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I think u didnt understand my question. Sending the sid to the action and then fetching the row against it is possible and i know that. But instead of that, i want to send a complete object to the action. I want to avoid the overhead of fetching the row in action. Is it possible in struts 2?

Comment: I think you don't understand a type conversion technique, that's why I've written what is possible, and according absence any other information a recommended link for *deep learning*.

Comment: i didnt actually understand, wht u r trying to say. Can u plz explain it with code? small piece of code that implement, wht u said above in ur answer. Thanks.